# A problem about the integration of blackbody radiation law using FormulaData. QuantityVariable limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, curated-data, units

I am trying to integrate blackbody radiation law under 1500 Kelvin using the [`FormulaData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormulaData.html) command.

The integration seems not to work properly after I designate the integration range. *Mathematica* does not return me the numeric value that I want, and there is no error message popping up. So I guess my command is actually not a problem?

**Is it because Mathematica simply cannot handle this kind of complicated integration?**

```
f = FormulaData[
      {"PlanckRadiationLaw", "Wavelength"}, 
      {"T" -> Quantity[1500, "Kelvins"]}
   ]

N[ Integrate[ f[[2]], {λ, 1*^-6, 10*^-6} ] ]
```

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

The first one is that the result of `FormulaData` is given in terms of `QuantityVariable` objects. Change them to normal symbols:

```
f = FormulaData[{"PlanckRadiationLaw", "Wavelength"}, {"T" -> Quantity[1500, "Kelvins"]}];
expr = f[[2]] /. QuantityVariable["\[Lambda]", "Wavelength"] -> lambda;
```

The second is that you should use `Quantity` values for the limits of integration:

```
N[Integrate[expr, {lambda, Quantity[1, "Micrometers"], Quantity[10, "Micrometers"]}]]
(* Quantity[87362.1, ("Kilograms")/("Seconds")^3] *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It does work. uh, but it is a little bit strange, because I wrote my code based on the document of FormulaData and Quantity: [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormulaData.html), [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html). If you scroll down those two webpages, you will find some examples (and even exactly the blackbody radiation problem). It seems that those examples didn't change the output type of FormulaData and did directly use numbers to designate the integration limit (not Quantity). They worked however. So what is the difference

Comment: The examples you mention use a slightly different, but equivalent, method. Instead of changing QuantityVariable[...] by lambda and giving limits Quantity[1, "Micrometers"], etc, they change QuantityVariable[...] by Quantity[lambda, "Micrometers"] and then lambda has limits 1, etc. It doesn't matter where we give the units (either in the rule or in the integration limits), but those units must be given. A physical variable (the QuantityVariable[...] object returned by FormulaData) must be replaced by values (i.e. Quantity values) with units.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply because I have been busy these days...Yes, I think your answer is very helpful, where I learned that FormulaData returns a physical variable and requires both a unit and value. To prepare the returned formula for later use and manipulate the returned value, I need to somehow apply the desired quantity to the returned formula and "extract" the desired quantity for later use. Thanks for your illuminating advice!